# Terraform: How do I get all vnet details and iterate its subnet

Tags: terraform

In azure, I need to get Vnet details for a tenant and find all subnet details.

In terraform website we can iterate only one vnet with name and resource group.

Comment: What details do you want exactly? And what are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

Did this help you? Use data sources to get exist resources details.

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "test" {
  name                 = "backend"
  virtual_network_name = "production"
  resource_group_name  = "networking"
}

output "subnet_id" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_subnet.test.id}"
}
```

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html

Comment: I don't think this answers the question although it is a little unclear right now. The question specifically states that they want to find information (not stated exactly what) about all the subnets in a vnet.